# Calling functions if certain strings are in an array

Tags: react.js, typescript, redux

I have these few helper function that are used to check if the string in the given array is present and if the certain steps are present and then only have the other function fire. The reason I currently have them separated is because arrTours need to be associated with only those arrSteps. those will always be the values in those arrays

```
// Handles for manditory action needed by user
const arrTourOver = ['OverviewTour'];
const arrStepOver = [6, 7];
export const handleJoyrideOverview = (
  dispatch: any,
  tour: any,
  index: number
) => {
  arrTourOver.includes(tour?.openTour) &&
    arrStepOver.includes(tour?.stepIndex) &&
    JoyRideDelayContinue(dispatch, tour, tour?.openTour, index);
};

// Handles for manditory action needed by user
const arrTourResize = ['ResizingWidgets'];
const arrStepResize = [0, 1];
export const handleJoyrideResize = (
  dispatch: any,
  tour: any,
  index: number
) => {
  arrTourResize.includes(tour?.openTour) &&
    arrStepResize.includes(tour?.stepIndex) &&
    JoyRideDelayContinue(dispatch, tour, tour?.openTour, index);
};

// Handles for manditory action needed by user
const arrTourDock = ['DockbarFunctions'];
const arrStepDock = [3, 4];
export const handleJoyrideDock = (dispatch: any, tour: any, index: number) => {
  arrTourDock.includes(tour?.openTour) &&
    arrStepDock.includes(tour?.stepIndex) &&
    JoyRideDelayContinue(dispatch, tour, tour?.openTour, index);
};
```

These are the 3 I currently have but I will be adding a few more I just want to figure out reducing the redundancy before I keep going

this part isn't really needed but I'll put JoyRideDelayContinue function below just in case

```
export const JoyRideDelayContinue = (
  dispatch: any,
  tour: any,
  tourType: string,
  stepIndex: number
) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    if (tour && tour.openTour === tourType) {
      dispatch({ type: 'SET_OPEN_TOUR', payload: '' });
      dispatch({
        type: 'PROGRESS_NEXT_OR_PREV',
        payload: { type: tourType, stepIndex: stepIndex }
      });
      setTimeout(
        () => dispatch({ type: 'SET_OPEN_TOUR', payload: tourType }),
        500
      );
    }
  }, 1000);
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Define types

If you are using a typed language like TypeScript, you should use it correctly. Defining most of the variables as type `any` does not give you robust type protection. Using TypeScript this way is just bloating your code with noise.

### Low quality

Sorry to say this, but the code is rather low quality.

The code has a lot of repeated and some redundant code.

Data is unorganized and strewn ad-hoc in the code creating a maintenance nightmare.

Names are too long and you use pre and post fix naming to organize related data. That is what objects are for. You should seldomly need to use pre/post fixed naming in an OO language.

Your intent is not clear due to the way you use `?.` It is possible that you have used them correctly, but that is a very unusual situation and should be handled before you pass `tour` to any function.

Only export what you need. I have the feeling you have slapped export in front of code that will never be used outside the module.

### Rewrite

The rewrite moves the 3 functions into a factory. The data they need is passed as arguments.

The strings and steps are stored in 2 [Sets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to keep time complexity down.

I am assuming that `tour` is never nullish when passed and that you never put `undefined` in the string arrays or the numbers that include `undefined` which will negate the need for `?.`

All the `handleJoyride???` calls are added to an export object called `joyrides`. Thus

```
const arrTourOver = ['OverviewTour'];
const arrStepOver = [6, 7];
export const handleJoyrideOverview = (
```

becomes

```
export const joyrides = {
    overview: createDispatcher(['OverviewTour'], [6, 7]),
    ...
```

The resulting rewrite as Javascript

```
export const joyrides = {
   overview: createDispatcher(['OverviewTour'], [6, 7]),
   resize: createDispatcher(['ResizingWidgets'], [0, 1]),
   dock: createDispatcher(['DockbarFunctions'], [3, 4]),
};  

function createDispatcher(strs, steps, dispatcher = JoyRideDelayContinue){
    [strs, steps] = [new Set(strs), new Set(steps)];    
    return (dispatch, tour, idx) => {
        strs.has(tour.openTour) && steps.has(tour.stepsIndex) && 
        dispatcher(dispatch, tour, idx)
    };
}   

const JoyRideDelayContinue = (dispatch, tour, stepIndex) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        dispatch({type: 'SET_OPEN_TOUR', payload: ''});
        dispatch({type: 'PROGRESS_NEXT_OR_PREV', payload: {type: tour.openTour, stepIndex}});
        setTimeout(dispatch, 500, {type: 'SET_OPEN_TOUR', payload: tour.openTour})
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this feedback

Answer (score 4):

The first thing I would extract is the condition:

```javascript
const includesTourData = (tours, steps, tour) => tours.includes(tour?.openTour) && steps.includes(tour?.stepIndex) &&

const handleJoyrideDock = (dispatch: any, tour: any, index: number) =>
      includesTourData(arrTourDock, arrStepsDock, tour) &&    
      JoyRideDelayContinue(dispatch, tour, tour?.openTour, index);
```

I would improve the params of `JoyRideDelayContinue`, you're checking for equality inside the function `tour.openTour == tourType`, but at the call site you call it with `tour, tour?.openTour`, which is redundant:

```javascript
export const JoyRideDelayContinue = (
  dispatch: any,
  tour: any,
  stepIndex: number
) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
      dispatch({ type: 'SET_OPEN_TOUR', payload: '' });
      dispatch({
        type: 'PROGRESS_NEXT_OR_PREV',
        payload: { type: tour?.openTour, stepIndex }
      });
      setTimeout(
        () => dispatch({ type: 'SET_OPEN_TOUR', payload: tour?.openTour }),
        500
      );
  }, 1000);
};
```

Finally, I think that you are adding a level of unnecessary indirection with the `handleJoyrideDock`-like functions. You could just write the conditional logic at the call site.